# Issue with Kendo Asp.Net MVC Grid Popup template Add/Update record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo Asp.Net MVC Grid Control. 
I'm facing a problem while adding new record.

1) I'm Using  editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)

2) I'v created a template for new record.

3) In Template I'v Editor Control (Which allow enter text with HTLM tags like Paragraph , underline, bold letters, etc).

Up to here every thing good. :-)

Here is my problem:
When I enter text without adding HTML tags the New record is adding and Updating in the grid.
But, When I enter any HTML tags. It is not adding new record and updating grid.
I have added .Encoded(false) for Grid column and Editor Control(In Template)

Thanks in help.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the HTML value is posted non-encoded and triggers the ASP.NET request validation. If you check the browser console, you may see the infamous [potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client](https://www.google.com/search?q=potentially+dangerous+request.form+value+was+detected+from+the+client) message. Either disable security validation, or set the `AllowHtml` attribute on the model field that will receive the HTML string. Here is some more information about [request validation in ASP.NET](http://blogs.learnnowonline.com/blog/bid/199703/ASP-NET-MVC-Request-Validation-Protection-AllowHtml-Attribute).

Comment: I'm using the AllowHtml attribute in model and I have used [ValidateInput(false)]. Still it is not working. I'm thinking kendo grid row level update event is not accepting HTML data.